# Mongoose Model populate callback is not called when there are references

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use Mongoose's Model.populate() to convert a user ID into a User, within a substructure of a document which has been fetched through an aggregation and an unwind. I'm guessing there's either something wrong with my schema or the perhaps unwind is breaking the connection to the sub-schema.

**The problem is:** when there is a valid reference, the populate callback simply isn't called. When there is no substructure the callback is called, with the original document unchanged.

**Structure:**

I have Articles which can have none or many ArticleRatings each by a User.

I'm using two references in the ArticleRating, to relate to the Article and the User who made the rating.

**Process:**

The process is actually exporting the articles to a (legacy) CSV format and flattening the structure, into duplicate article rows with their user-specific ratings. Unwind is perfect for this operation, and preserve nulls retains articles with no ratings.

**Debugging:**

I've tried stepping deep into the Model.populate code. It gets pretty complex with all the promises and callback wrappers, but I can see that the underlying populate call isn't calling the internal callbacks either. I'm not using the promise variant - but not 100% sure if I should be? (the Mongoose docs are a bit vague on the use-cases between callbacks and promises).

I've double checked my schema, tried explicitly adding the model to the populate call (which shouldn't be needed as it's in the schema). There are no errors or exceptions, it doesn't crash.

Stepping through the code in the Chrome debugger shows the model just as I'd expect: the first few Articles have a rating.userId with a valid ObjectId, but in those cases the populate callback simply doesn't get called. The next hundred Articles have no "rating" set, and the callback gets called reliably for all of them.

So I'm guessing something I'm doing wrong is leading Model.populate down a path where it's not erroring properly?

Note: I know I could rewrite the code to use aggregate $lookup or other embedding structures rather than the foreign reference, but I'm at the final piece of a feature jigsaw and would like to get this working as-is.

This is the simplified schema:

```
const ArticleRatingSchema = new Schema({
    articleId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Article'},
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},                          
    rating: String,                                                                                                             
    comment: String,                                                                                                        
});

const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    rating: ArticleRatingSchema,
});
```

And this is the lookup

```
    // Find all articles relating to this project, and their ratings.
    // Unwind does the duplicate per-user, and preserve keeps un-rated articles.
    articleModel.aggregate([
            {$match: {projectId: projectId}},
            {$lookup:{from:'articleratings', localField:'_id', foreignField:'articleId', as:'rating' }},
            {$unwind: {path:'$rating', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}}
        ], (err, models) =>
    {
        if (!err) {

            models.map((article) => {

                articleModel.populate(article, {path:'rating.userId', model:'User'}, (err, article)=> {
                    // Process the article...
                    // this callback only gets called where there is NO rating in the article.
                });

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised it's because I'm processing the set in a synchronous map() loop, and the two cases must be different in that the non-matching populate is a synchronous callback whereas the matching replacements callback later.

If I console.log() in the callback, I find that the the four matching cases are processed last after the CSV has already been formatted and downloaded.

So the answer is: populate IS being called, but asynchronously.

I need to rework the map() loop to accomodate the usual async pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally more than a bit baffled by where you think you are going with using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in an aggregation pipeline and then wanting `.populate()` the results. Because asking to use `.populate()` essentially means that additional queries are being issued to the server in order to "emulate a join".

Therefore since [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) actually does the "join on the server" then you really should be just using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) for this.

You can use `.populate()` and I'll show some code to show that it can be done. But it really is redundant here since you may as well just do all the work on the server.

So my best "approximation" of what you seem to have as a structure is:

**articles**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb16"),
        "title" : "New News",
        "ratings" : [ ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

**articleratings**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb17"),
        "articleId" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb16"),
        "userId" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb13"),
        "rating" : "5",
        "comment" : "Great!",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb18"),
        "articleId" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb16"),
        "userId" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb14"),
        "rating" : "3",
        "comment" : "Okay I guess ;)",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb19"),
        "articleId" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb16"),
        "userId" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb15"),
        "rating" : "1",
        "comment" : "Hated it :<",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

**users**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb13"),
        "name" : "Bill",
        "email" : "bill@example.com",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb14"),
        "name" : "Fred",
        "email" : "fred@example.com",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5962104312246235cdcceb15"),
        "name" : "Ted",
        "email" : "ted@example.com",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

And then the aggregate statement:

```
  Article.aggregate(
    [
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": ArticleRating.collection.name,
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "articleId",
        "as": "ratings"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$ratings" },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": User.collection.name,
        "localField": "ratings.userId",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "ratings.userId",
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$ratings.userId" },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "title": { "$first": "$title" },
        "ratings": { "$push": "$ratings" }
      }}
    ],
    (err,articles) => {
      if (err) callback(err);
      log(articles);
      callback();
    }
  )
```

With the result:

```
  {
    "_id": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd94",
    "title": "New News",
    "ratings": [
      {
        "_id": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd95",
        "articleId": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd94",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd91",
          "name": "Bill",
          "email": "bill@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "5",
        "comment": "Great!",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd96",
        "articleId": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd94",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd92",
          "name": "Fred",
          "email": "fred@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "3",
        "comment": "Okay I guess ;)",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd97",
        "articleId": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd94",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "5962126f3ef2fb35efeefd93",
          "name": "Ted",
          "email": "ted@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "1",
        "comment": "Hated it :<",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

Where it does not make sense to "populate" the references to the "articleId" on the "ratings" themselves. But we have indeed "populated" the "ratings" to the article, and the "user" for each rating.

---

### Example Listing

Shows it both ways, using `.populate()` ( after [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) ) like you are trying, and also just using the plain [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Methods use both "plain promises"  and alternate with [`async.map`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map):

```
const async = require('async'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/publication');

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const articleRatingSchema = new Schema({
  articleId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Article'},
  userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
  rating: String,
  comment: String,
});

const articleSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  ratings: [articleRatingSchema]
})

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
const ArticleRating = mongoose.model('ArticleRating', articleRatingSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}


const userData = [
  { name: 'Bill', rating: 5, comment: 'Great!' },
  { name: 'Fred', rating: 3, comment: 'Okay I guess ;)' },
  { name: 'Ted',  rating: 1, comment: 'Hated it :<' }
];

async.series(
  [
    // Clean data
    (callback) =>
      async.each(mongoose.models,(model,callback) =>
        model.remove({},callback),callback),

    // Insert data
    (callback) =>
      async.waterfall(
        [
          // User and article
          (callback) =>
            async.parallel(
              {
                "users": (callback) =>
                  User.create(
                    ["Bill", "Fred", "Ted"].map( name =>
                      ({ name, email: `${name.toLowerCase()}@example.com` })
                    ),
                    callback
                  ),

                "article": (callback) =>
                  Article.create({ title: "New News" },callback)
              },
              callback
            ),

          // Article Ratings
          (data,callback) =>
            ArticleRating.create(
              data.users.map( u => ({
                articleId: data.article._id,
                userId: u._id,
                rating: userData.find( ud => ud.name === u.name ).rating,
                comment: userData.find( ud => ud.name === u.name ).comment
              })),
              callback
            )
        ],
        callback
      ),

    // $lookup and populate async.map
    (callback) =>
      Article.aggregate(
        [
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": ArticleRating.collection.name,
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "articleId",
            "as": "ratings"
          }}
        ],
        (err,articles) => {
          if (err) callback(err);
          async.map(
            articles.map( a => new Article(a) ),
            (article,callback) =>
              async.map(
                article.ratings,
                (rating,callback) =>
                  ArticleRating.populate(rating,{ path: 'userId' },callback),
                (err,ratings) => {
                  if (err) callback(err);
                  article.ratings = ratings
                  callback(null,article)
                }
              ),
            (err,articles) => {
              if (err) callback(err);
              log(articles);
              callback();
            }
          )
        }
      ),


    // $look and populate Promise
    (callback) =>
      Article.aggregate(
        [
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": ArticleRating.collection.name,
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "articleId",
            "as": "ratings"
          }}
        ]
      )
      .then(articles =>
        Promise.all(
          articles.map( a => new Article(a) ).map(article =>
            new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
              Promise.all(
                article.ratings.map( rating =>
                  ArticleRating.populate(rating,{ path: 'userId' })
                )
              ).then(ratings => {
                article.ratings = ratings;
                resolve(article);
              }).catch(reject)
            })
          )
        )
      )
      .then(articles => {
        log(articles);
        callback();
      })
      .catch(err => callback(err)),


    // Plain $lookup
    (callback) =>
      Article.aggregate(
        [
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": ArticleRating.collection.name,
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "articleId",
            "as": "ratings"
          }},
          { "$unwind": "$ratings" },
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": User.collection.name,
            "localField": "ratings.userId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "ratings.userId",
          }},
          { "$unwind": "$ratings.userId" },
          { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title": { "$first": "$title" },
            "ratings": { "$push": "$ratings" }
          }}
        ],
        (err,articles) => {
          if (err) callback(err);
          log(articles);
          callback();
        }
      )
  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

**Full Output**

```
Mongoose: users.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: articles.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: articleratings.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: users.insert({ name: 'Bill', email: 'bill@example.com', _id: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed40"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: users.insert({ name: 'Fred', email: 'fred@example.com', _id: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed41"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: users.insert({ name: 'Ted', email: 'ted@example.com', _id: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed42"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: articles.insert({ title: 'New News', _id: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43"), ratings: [], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: articleratings.insert({ articleId: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43"), userId: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed40"), rating: '5', comment: 'Great!', _id: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed44"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: articleratings.insert({ articleId: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43"), userId: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed41"), rating: '3', comment: 'Okay I guess ;)', _id: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed45"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: articleratings.insert({ articleId: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43"), userId: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed42"), rating: '1', comment: 'Hated it :<', _id: ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed46"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: articles.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'articleratings', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'articleId', as: 'ratings' } } ], {})
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed40") ] } }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed41") ] } }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed42") ] } }, { fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
    "title": "New News",
    "__v": 0,
    "ratings": [
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed44",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed40",
          "name": "Bill",
          "email": "bill@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "5",
        "comment": "Great!",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed45",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed41",
          "name": "Fred",
          "email": "fred@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "3",
        "comment": "Okay I guess ;)",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed46",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed42",
          "name": "Ted",
          "email": "ted@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "1",
        "comment": "Hated it :<",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
Mongoose: articles.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'articleratings', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'articleId', as: 'ratings' } } ], {})
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed40") ] } }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed41") ] } }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("596219ff6f73ed36d868ed42") ] } }, { fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
    "title": "New News",
    "__v": 0,
    "ratings": [
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed44",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed40",
          "name": "Bill",
          "email": "bill@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "5",
        "comment": "Great!",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed45",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed41",
          "name": "Fred",
          "email": "fred@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "3",
        "comment": "Okay I guess ;)",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed46",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed42",
          "name": "Ted",
          "email": "ted@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "1",
        "comment": "Hated it :<",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
Mongoose: articles.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'articleratings', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'articleId', as: 'ratings' } }, { '$unwind': '$ratings' }, { '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: 'ratings.userId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'ratings.userId' } }, { '$unwind': '$ratings.userId' }, { '$group': { _id: '$_id', title: { '$first': '$title' }, ratings: { '$push': '$ratings' } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
    "title": "New News",
    "ratings": [
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed44",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed40",
          "name": "Bill",
          "email": "bill@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "5",
        "comment": "Great!",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed45",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed41",
          "name": "Fred",
          "email": "fred@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "3",
        "comment": "Okay I guess ;)",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed46",
        "articleId": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed43",
        "userId": {
          "_id": "596219ff6f73ed36d868ed42",
          "name": "Ted",
          "email": "ted@example.com",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "rating": "1",
        "comment": "Hated it :<",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```